# JavaScript: reorder array based on numbers within array items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to unscramble an array. The array has string items out of order with a number attached to specify what the order should be. I want to take the number within the array item and reassign the array item index to reflect that number. For example `var scrambled = ["pizza4", "to2", "I0", "eat3", "want1"]`. I have a function that searches the array for the number attached and returns the value. Now I want to take the value returned and turn it into the new item's index in a new array, like `var unscrambled = []`. This is what I have so far:

```
function unscramblePhrase() {
    var scrambled = ["pizza4", "to2", "I0", "eat3", "want1"];   
    var unscrambled = [];
    for (var counter = 0; counter < scrambled.length; counter++) {
        numPosition = scrambled[counter].search('[0-9]');
        arrayIndex = scrambled[counter].substring(numPosition);
        console.log(arrayIndex);
        unscrambled.push(scrambled[arrayIndex]);
    }
 console.log(unscrambled)
}
```

I see that my arrayIndex is pulling the numbers from the end of the scrambled array items but my attempt at assigning index position based off this variable is producing a newly scrambled array: `["want1", "I0", "pizza4", "eat3", "to2"]`.

Comment: What if the strings contain more than one number: `"abc10def22"`? What if there are strings with the same number: `["abc12", "def12"]`? What if there is a missing number: `["abc0", "def3"]` (`2` is missing)?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir was thinking the same. Obviously this is a very specific case. As OP mentioned, he already has a method for extracting the number from the string.

Comment: For the purpose of this example. assume that the array has all the correct numbers (0-4) and no duplicates.

Comment: What do you want as output?

Comment: I want it to read "I0 want1 to2 eat3 pizza4."

Comment: your solution is almost correct you just need to instatiate the whole array first and NOT push but rather assign, eg `unscrambled = new Array(scrambled.length)` then assign in the loop like:`unscrambled[arrayIndex] = scrambled[counter];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the best way to sort an array, but your issue is that your using `Array.prototype.push`, when you should just be assigning the value to an index in `unscrambled`.

```
unscrambled[arrayIndex] = scrambled[counter];
```

#### But the real way to do this is with [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
function getNum(str){
    return Number(str.substring(str.length -1));
}


unscrambled.sort((a, b) => getNum(a) - getNum(b));
```

> **Note:** This method sorts your array [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm). This may be good, or not good depending on your requirements
>
> But you can always use it on a clone:
>
> ```
> [...unscrambled].sort((a, b) => getNum(a) - getNum(b));
> ```

Comment: dont forget to instantiate the `unscrambled` array first like `unscrambled = new Array(scrambled.length);`

Comment: no this can create reference issues as the array has to grow dynamicaly during assignment which is not supported to work by all browsers, instead instantaiate it with the correct size before-hand

Comment: @NikosM. What browsers don't support dynamically growing arrays?

Comment: @dovidweisz, actually no browsers supports dynamicaly growing an array by random assignment to one index position. What is done is that the index is added as dynamic property in the array object and not as array index per se. Anyway details, better to instatiate the whole array since the size is known and THEN any index is indeed available for assignment NOT simply adding dynamic properties in the object

Comment: @NikosM. If what you're saying is true, we can verify it by checking `array.length`.

Comment: @dovidweisz, yes that would do but again not all browsers will support it (certainly older IE wont)

Comment: @NikosM. I'm not advocating the practice. It's bad because it makes it hard for the  JS engine to optimize your code. Still what browser doesn't support it?

Comment: @dovidweisz on the top of my head older IE (<10) and maybe older vbersions of firefox and chrome but these dont matter much as they are evergreen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183649/discussion-between-dovidweisz-and-nikos-m).

Comment: @dovidweisz, dont have time to chat sorry, if what I said is not the case it is fine, even code optisation is important and growing an array dynamicaly is poor practice anyway

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify this by using RegEx to split the array into value and index, sort them, and then remove the additional information using a secondary `.map` to return the string array.

```
scrambled.map(i => 
[i.replace(/\d/g,""), +i.replace(/\D/g,"")])
.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])).map(i => i[0]);
```

```js
var scrambled = ["pizza4", "to2", "I0", "eat3", "want1"];   

var unscrambled = scrambled.map(i => 
  [i.replace(/\d/g,""), +i.replace(/\D/g,"")])
  .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
  .map( i => i[0]);

console.log(unscrambled);
```

Comment: Why use `Array.from` on an array (new array, not the original)?

Comment: Obviously an excellent answer, but I think it will not be great for OP because it seems like he is still learning JS, and this is a pretty fancy ES6 snippet. Either way, very nice.

Comment: @SamCreamer thanks! It looks fancy admittedly, but it's actually rather simple. I think being shown code that is maybe a little intimidating is a good thing, as it teaches you new techniques and patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (no clue if it works):

`function unscramblePhrase() {
    var scrambled = ["pizza4", "to2", "I0", "eat3", "want1"];

    var unscrambled = [];
    for (var counter = 0; counter < scrambled.length; counter++) {
        numPosition = scrambled[counter].search('[0-9]');
        arrayIndex = scrambled[counter].substring(numPosition);
        console.log(arrayIndex);
        unscrambled[arrayIndex] = scrambled[counter];
    }
 console.log(unscrambled)
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop and take the parts of the string and the index, assign the value to the index and return the array.

```js
var scrambled = ["pizza4", "to2", "I0", "eat3", "want1"],
    result = scrambled.reduce((r, string) => {
        var [s, i] = string.match(/\D+|\d+/g);
        r[i] = s;
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

More fun with objects.

```js
var scrambled = ["pizza4", "to2", "I0", "eat3", "want1"],
    result = Object.assign(
        [],
        ...scrambled.map(s => (([v, k]) => ({ [k]: v }))(s.match(/\D+|\d+/g)))
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice answer! As silly as it may sound I was completely unaware that you could assign to any index in an array before the array was formed!

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt with "Array.sort" as well like below

```js
var scrambled = ["pizza4", "to2", "I0", "eat3", "want1"]

let getNumberIndex = (d) => [...d].findIndex(v => Number.isInteger(+v))

let getNumber = (d) => d.slice(getNumberIndex(d))

let unscrambled = scrambled.slice(0).sort((a,b) => getNumber(a) - getNumber(b))

console.log(unscrambled)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const words = ["I0", "want1", "to2", "eat3", "pizza4"]

words
    .map (w => parseInt (w [--w.length]))
    .sort ()
    .map (i => words.filter (w => w [--w.length] == i) [0].replace (i, ''))

// ["I", "want", "to", "eat", "pizza"]
```